# Grails: Jasper plugin error on Linux - java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: java, grails, plugins, jasper-reports

Everything works fine on my local machine. But as soon as I get it on a Linux box (CentOS), the following error comes up while generating the report:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
```

Code where it happens is:

```
jasperService.generateReport(reportDef)
```

I have made sure the JDK on my local laptop and server are same. I am using Jasper 4.0.1 that is used by default in the [Jasper plugin 1.2.1](http://grails.org/plugin/jasper).

Any ideas? I have spent quite a bit of time to resolve this without any luck.

Here is a better stack trace.

```
=======================================================================================
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5bda8ba8.generateReport(<generated>)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperService$generateReport.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
..
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
...
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
.....
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
....    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:372)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(SimpleGrailsControllerHelper.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:292)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:251)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:245)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:366)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.filter.GrailsReloadServletFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsReloadServletFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:249)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:228)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:216)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:199)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager$compileReport.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperService.generatePrinter(JasperService.groovy:230)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperService.this$2$generatePrinter(JasperService.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperService$this$2$generatePrinter.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperService.generateReport(JasperService.groovy:103)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$903b2389.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    ... 135 more
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:684)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:554)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1619)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1657)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:193)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)null
Report not Generated!
```

Comment: can you provide more detailed stacktrace?

Comment: 2011-07-24 04:43:41,910 [http-8080-5] ERROR appName.Service - java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

Comment: This is "message", there is must a stacktrace under this message. Please add it into your question

Comment: definitely need the full stack trace!

Comment: No other stacktrace before/after this message. Other messages are my app message saying report generated or not. I looked under /bin/stacktrace.log but no messages there as well.apply [report_id:2, report_begin_date:Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 UTC 1969,
 report_end_date:Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 UTC 1969, SUBREPORT_DIR:/usr/share/apache-t
omcat-6.0.32/webapps/../reports/ghgReport, REPORT_LOCALE:en_US]
2011-07-24 16:09:42,774 [http-8080-4] ERROR appName.Service
- java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
Report not Generated!
params:======[reportId:1, oId:2, action:reportFile, controller:controllerName]

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and fixed the problem. The solution was located in the [plugin FAQ](http://grails.org/plugin/jasper), at the `MalformedByteSequenceException` paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check that **all** the dependencies match the ones your using on your local server.  There might be an outdated dependency on your remote server and it's probably one that the jasper or jasper plugin is using and may not be jasper itself.  Also, check to see if your local or remote server has any bundled dependencies that maybe cause this (log4j?).

Comment: I built the remote linux server myself. Tried it on different hosts (AWSand and rackspace). Even I rebuilt the local environment on new laptop.

Comment: One more thing: my local env is windows 7. Unless there is some lib on CentOS (linux) by default which is causing this. By the way same error comes with Tomcat 6 or 7 on linux. Only basic difference between remote and local is linux and windows 7.

Comment: I do get following error when app is deployed, but app works fine except for creation of jasper report. 
INFO: Deploying web application archive appName.war
Jul 24, 2011 10:27:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/appName/WEB-INF
/lib/servlet-api-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2.
 Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations
.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: Could you post this in your question so others may see it as well?