# Jasper iReport - creating report in development and deploying it to production

Tags: grails, plugins, jasper-reports

How to create a jasper report with devl database and then deploy to prod with prod datasource?

Steps:
Use iReport to create jasper report.
Define  devl DB as datasorce.
compile and test it.
Once working fine, change the datasource to prod DB, compile and deploy it to prod. That should work correct?

I tried these steps. But I am getting error once I depoy app in production. I opened another thread for that specific question, but just want to make sure I am doing the right thing. Here is the link for that error:

[Grails: Jasper plugin error on Linux - java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805020/grails-jasper-plugin-error-on-linux-java-lang-reflect-undeclaredthrowableexcep)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you actually try those steps? If not, do it... seems correct

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with deploy on diferent environments (development, pre production, production) using Jdeploy, a useful command line deploy tool on https://sourceforge.net/projects/jaspertools/?source=directory
It allows to manage datasources on isolated way, so deploy only applies to a report and resources.